# VBA code to open a changing file name

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to figure out a line of code to open a file.
The path is constant, that is

```
"H:\silly\goose\*filename.xlsm*"
```

However, this file name will change each time I try to run this macro.  This is because I will be using this macro to automate a report which I run weekly.  Each report is saved with the date in the title and all reports are kept in the same folder, meaning I can't just start naming them all the same.
Examples:

> H:\silly\goose\Report 06-03-15.xlsm
>   H:\silly\goose\Report 05-27-15.xlsm

The only helping piece of information is that this report is to be run every Wednesday.  Therefore, each filename will have a difference of 7 days.  I don't know if there is anything I can do with the `Date` method here, though.

Comment: Can you show the code that you use to *save* the filename? The logic should be nearly identical.

Comment: Otherwise, we need more information. How should the application know *which* file to open? Does it always open the *most recent* file (i.e., the one produced <= 7 days ago?

Comment: Using the 2 examples you gave, we know that "06-03-15">"05-27-15". Loop through the filenames doing this comparison, if true then make the new file comparison the filename to open, the highest number will naturally bubble to the surface.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is re-construct your file name first.

```
Const fpath As String = "H:\silly\goose\" ' your fixed folder
Dim fname As String

' Below gives you the Wednesday of the week
fname = Format(Date - (Weekday(Date) - 1) + 3, "mm-dd-yy") ' returns 06-03-15 if run today
fname = "Report " & fname & ".xlsm" ' returns Report 06-03-15.xlsm
fname = fpath & fname ' returns H:\silly\goose\Report 06-03-15.xlsm
```

Then execute opening of the file:

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fname)
If wb Is Nothing Then MsgBox "File does not exist": Exit Sub

' Rest of your code goes here which works on wb Object
```

Comment: could you explain what this line means?: Format(Date - Weekday(Date) + 3, "mm-dd-yy")       I removed your -1 because this macro should always be run on a Wednesday.  However, I still don't understand the Weekday(Date)+3

Comment: @Tawm That simple gets the date of the *Wednesday* of the week so that you'll create a file out of it. So this week, it returns *6/3/2015* but running it next week will return *6/10/2013*. Now, if this is not what you need, revise your question accordingly and explain a bit more what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[This reference](http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/getting_a_list_of_file_names_using_vba/) has this function:

```
Function GetFileList(FileSpec As String) As Variant
'   Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'   If no matching files are found, it returns False

    Dim FileArray() As Variant
    Dim FileCount As Integer
    Dim FileName As String

    On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

    FileCount = 0
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec)
    If FileName = "" Then GoTo NoFilesFound

'   Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount) = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    GetFileList = FileArray
    Exit Function

'   Error handler
NoFilesFound:
    GetFileList = False
End Function
```

Now you can do:

```
p = "H:\silly\goose\*.xlsm"
x = GetFileList(p)
```

And get the file you want